# Ask for state in ng-show / ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I only want to show specific navigation points (profile, friends) when the current state is not the state "landing". Im using AngularJS together with ui-router, if i do the following, it doesn't seem to work:

```
ng-hide="$state == 'landing'"
```

Any suggestions on how to ask for the state in ng-show / ng-hide?

Comment: use $state.current.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your issue

```
<div ng-hide="$state.current.name == 'landing'"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$state.includes('landing')` in your js. It defines current state.

For example:

```
if($state.includes('landing')){
   $scope.hide = true;
}
```

Then in your HTML :

```
ng-hide = "hide";
```